# Unable to get HDD no in client machine

Tags: c#, wmi

I am retrieving the hdd manufacture serial number in a c# project on my development machine with the class `System.management`.

But when I deployed the program onto a client machine, I cannot retrieve the hdd no and instead get the value `4c354541464134542202020202020202020220202020202` in palace of the hdd no.

i also add `system.management.dll` in my setup, but I am still unable to get hdd no.

My code is:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher moSearcher = new
ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

foreach (ManagementObject wmi_HD in moSearcher.Get())
{
    ArrayList hardDriveDetails = new ArrayList();
    HardDrive hd = new HardDrive();  // User Defined Class
    hd.Model = wmi_HD["Model"].ToString();  //Model Number
    hd.Type = wmi_HD["InterfaceType"].ToString();  //Interface Type
    hd.SerialNo = wmi_HD["SerialNumber"].ToString(); //Serial Number
    hardDriveDetails.Add(hd);
    // label1.Text = "Model : " + hd.Model;
    //label2.Text = " Type : " + hd.Type;
    label5.Text = "Your serial no. is: " + hd.SerialNo.Trim();
    // MessageBox.Show(hd.SerialNo);

    if (hd.SerialNo.Trim().Equals("WDEESC4E"))
    {
       // btnDownload.Enabled = true;
        //btnImport.Enabled = true;
        //btnShow.Enabled = true;
        btnValidate.Enabled = true;
        btnReset.Enabled = true;


    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please activate software.");
        btnDownload.Enabled = false;
        btnImport.Enabled = false;
        btnShow.Enabled = false;
        btnValidate.Enabled = false;
        btnReset.Enabled = false;

    }

}
```

Comment: "WDEESC4E" looks more like a model number than a serial number to me.

Comment: Hex `4c35454146413454` is the ASCII string `L5EAFA4T`

Comment: thanks a lot . it worked.

Comment: but when i run same program on my development machine then program showing proper hdd no in ascii.